# System.InvalidOperationException thrown during CreateFolderAsync

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I want to get a folder in my constructor. So, I need a non-async method.

```
    public static Windows.Storage.StorageFolder getStorageImagesDir()
    {
        Windows.Storage.StorageFolder folder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFolderAsync("images", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists).GetResults();

        return folder;
    }
```

However, `System.InvalidOperationException` was thrown, if the folder doesn't exist for the first time. (Somehow the folder is still created, even the exception is thrown)

When folder is already exist, the function works fine.

May I know anything wrong with my code?

**In Desktop .NET, Java, Python, ... we can perform folder creation, withn a simple single line of API call. For instance, `Directory.CreateDirectory` in .NET, `File.mkdirs` in Java, ... So, why in Windows Store App, we need to do it in async way? Doesn't it make simple thing unnecessary complicated?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the code from someone in MSDN.

```
StorageFolder folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFolderAsync("images", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists)
                               .AsTask()
                               .Result;
return folder;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are trying to perform an asynchronous operation in the constructor. The constructor itself is not asynchronous so you are likely trying to run an operation (GetResults) before the folder is actually created.

You have two options:

1. You can create an async method, and within that method await the call to get async to initialize, or
2. You can move the folder code out of the constructor and provide some explicit initialization.

Either way, the only valid reference to a folder you'll get is if you await the asynchronous operation. Otherwise it will return before the operation completed.

Comment: May I know why `GetResults` call may yield `System.InvalidOperationException`? I thought GetResults means, "Wait till folder is finished created, and return the folder as result to caller"?

Comment: and why can't we have a simple form `Directory.CreateDirectory`? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54a0at6s.aspx Making directory creation as asynchronous is unnecessary in my personal view. It makes thing unnecessary complicated

Comment: Any disk IO operation is a great candidate for async programming.  Disk access is notoriously slow and can be impacted by many other processes. What if there is a background process that is pushing the disk to 100% usage and it will be doing so for the next five minutes (video processing comes to mind).  Should your app completely stop for five minutes until the folder is created?

Comment: @JohnKoerner Ya. I get what you mean. Theoritically it is. But in reality, does a single folder creation ever take 5 minutes? If it ever, user will blame for the hardware, not the software. :) What I really want to bring out is, Microsoft should provide both async and non-aysnc of I/O functions. We, developers, are smart enough to choose in between.

Comment: @YanChengCHEOK Microsoft has done that in the full framework and they have found (I'll have to find the whitepaper) that people stick with the synchronous methods almost exclusively because it is easier to program with.  This causes adverse affects in some applications, so they decided to go full async and make the programmers work for it.

Comment: @JohnKoerner Wow. I don't even know they have whitepaper regarding programmer habits. Nice try Microsoft for trying to change my programming habit. But I'm not going to fall into your trap :)